# RMSE value of LSTM model vs ARIMA model

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a question that is a little bit confusing,, 
I have developed three models and one of them is LSTM,,, 
for the LSTM model ( I scaled the data -1,1 ) and run the model,, and to make a fair comparison with other models ( statistical models (ARIMA) required no scale and normalization developed on raw data) I got LSTM RMSE value so is this value a final one or should I convert it?

if anyone can please can help I would very much appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should do a conversion.

You’re effectively measuring your LSTM in feet and your other modes in meters (or miles and kilometers). The comparison is not fair. So LSTM has an error of 6 and ARIMA an error of 7...if the units aren’t the same (they’re not) then you cannot say which is performing better.

This has nothing to do with LSTM or neural networks. If you did yet another ARIMA mode but with scaled data, you would have to do some kind of conversion.

(I am assuming you’ve scaled your response variable. Since you’re considering an autoregression, it seems like you have just a univariate time series that you’ve scaled, meaning that you’ve scaled the response variable. I think you know this, but I want this comment here for someone coming by and getting confused.)

Comment: yes I have univariate for ARIMA model but for LSTM I have included other predictors but the target is univariate

Comment: @Feddah that doesn’t change my post but is an interesting clarification.